# Searching through list for words containing character

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to programming and am in an introductory course using python. I am trying to implement a function that takes a list of strings and a character as a parameter and prints to the screen, all the strings that have the given character in them. If the list is empty, the function returns 'List is empty'. So it should look like this:

Given:

```
wordsWithChar(['Absolute','IDE','Summary','Sense','Test'],'s')
```

Return:

```
Absolute Sense Test
```

Given:

```
wordsWithChar([],'r')
```

return:

```
'List is Empty'
```

EDIT:
I have tried the following:

```
def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
    for word in lst:
        print(word,end=' ')
    print()
    if len(lst)<1:
       print('List is empty')

def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
    for word in lst:
       print (word)
          if x in word:
              print(word)

def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
    newlst=[]
        for word in lst:
            newlst.append(word)
        print(newlst)
        if len(lst)<1:
            print('List is empty')
        if x in word:
           newlst.append(x)
        print(newlst)        
 
def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
    newlst=[]
    for word in lst:
        if x in lst:
           newlst.append(word)
    return newlst

    print(' ',join(lst))
    newlst=wordsWithChar(lst,x)
    if len(newlst)<1:
        print('List is empty')
    else:
        print(newlst)
```

I have tried everything I know with for-loops and if/else statements and cannot figure this out. Thank you in advance for the help.

EDIT: While I appreciate all the help, with every solution presented, IDLE gets to the wordsWithChar test and just stops. It for some reason does not return any values. just skips to a new input line.

Comment: Hint: Use the `in` keyword. `'y' in 'Python' == True` `'s' in 'Python' == False`

Comment: just edited to add what i tried. sorry im new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly nailed it:

```
  def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
    for word in lst:
       print (word)
    if x in word:
       print(word)
```

The indentation of the `if` statement makes it run *after* the loop. But you would want it to run *inside* the loop:

```py
def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
  for word in lst:
    if x in word:
      print(word)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  wordsWithChar(['Absolute','IDE','Summary','Sense','Test'],'s')
```

This does not show the "not found" message. A more pythonic way would be to first create the list of words containing x using a *list comprehension*:

```py
words_containing_x =  [ w for w in lst if x in w ]
# words_containing_x = ['Absolute', 'Sense', 'Test']
```

Broken down:

1. `words_containing_x =`  - the new list
2. `[ w for w  in lst ...]` the new list is all `w` in the lists - a copy
3. `[... if x in w]` but only if the word `w` contains `x`

If this is a bit confusing, the the following will return the `length` of all words in `lst` that contain `x`:

```py
len_of_words_containing_x =  [ len(w) for w in lst if x in w ]
# len_of_words_containing_x = [8, 5, 4]
```

Back to the question. The list can be tested:

```py
def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
  words_containing_x =  [ w for w in lst if x in w ]
  if words_containing_x:
    print(words_containing_x)
  else:
    print("Oh noes!")
```

Comment: Sorry that is a typo in the question. I have tried running it inside the for loop and still nothing

Comment: Thank you so much, that one helped a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Note this implementation is rudimentary and not by any means the only or ideal way to look for words containing a specific character.

Also note, this implementation only looks for the exact character match. So `wordsWithChar(['Absolute','IDE','Summary','Sense','Test'],'s')` and `wordsWithChar(['Absolute','IDE','Summary','Sense','Test'],'S')` (note the upper and lowercase s) are not the same questions

```
def wordsWithChar(words, char):
    words_with_char = []
    
    for word in words:
        if char in word:
            words_with_char.append(word)
    
    if len(words_with_char)<1:
        print('List is empty')
    else:
        print(' '.join(words_with_char))

words = ['Absolute','IDE','Summary','Sense','Test']
char = 's'

words_with_char = wordsWithChar(words, char)
```

Comment: this returns nothing when ran for some reason

Comment: Running the exact code I presented results in `Absolute IDE Summary Sense Test` `['Absolute', 'Sense', 'Test']` for me. Make sure you're using Python 3. How are you testing this code? Perhaps you have an indentation issue from copy and paste?

Comment: I am retyping the exact code you presented and it returns nothing. I type the code in a module then save and run. I have to do this since the problem contains multiple defs which must be ran when the module is ran in IDLE. for some reason, it just stops after printing "Starting wordsWithChar tests:" and just goes to a new line

Comment: update: fixed some indents and now get the following: Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 90, in <module>
    wordsWithChar([],'r')
  line 55, in wordsWithChar
    words_with_char = wordsWithChar(words, char)
   line 55, in wordsWithChar
    words_with_char = wordsWithChar(words, char)
 , in wordsWithChar
    words_with_char = wordsWithChar(words, char)
  [Previous line repeated 1022 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: You're requesting that the function does not return the values, simply prints them? Updated to match.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a nested for loop would be your best bet. I dont want to just straight up give you the answer especially since this is for a course but try this as a starting point

```
def words_with_character(lst, char):
    new_lst = []
    for word in lst:
        for x in word:
```

noticed `char` is unused. You should be able to figure out where it is meant to be implemented. Good luck coding!

Hmm actaully your solution is very close.

```
def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
newlst=[]
for word in lst:
    if x in lst:
        newlst.append(word)
return newlst
```

Would work but you have the indents all wrong. Indentation is every important in Python. Additonal you never use `word` within the loop

```
def wordsWithChar(lst,x):
    newlst=[]
    for word in lst:
        if x in word: # word is the wrong variable to use here
            newlst.append(word)
    return newlst
```

Comment: My professor provided the def line and gave those variables. I was under the assumption that 'x' was taking place of 'char'

Comment: char is independent of x in this case. Think of x as a temporary variable that is dependent on the iteration of the loop. So the first time the loop runs `word='Absolute` and `x='A'`. The second loop will go through all the letters in Absolute before moving on to IDE and repeating the process

Comment: Actually check out @Jens answer it is probably closer to what you are looking for